# Why is a morphism dominating? (In GIT by Mumford)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions, schemes, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an algebraic group acting on a scheme X, and $\phi:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes. We define the subsheaf of invariants $\mathcal I_\phi$ of $\phi_*\mathcal O_X$ by the fact that for any open subset $U$ of $Y$, a section $f\in\Gamma(U,\phi_*\mathcal O_X)=\Gamma(\phi^{-1}(U),\mathcal O_X)$ belongs to $\Gamma(U,\mathcal I_\phi)$ if and only if the following diagram commutes, where $\sigma$ stands for the action, $p_2$ for the projection on the second factor, and $F$ for the morphism induced by $f$.

[image]

I read, in Mumford's GIT book, that if $\mathcal O_Y$ is the subscheaf of invariants of $\phi_*\mathcal O_X$, then $\phi$ is dominating. Why?

Comment: I suppose $\phi$ is dominating as in is 'dominant morphism'?

Comment: @EvansGambit Yes!

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ both are integral schemes, and if the map $\mathcal{O}_Y\to \phi_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is injective, then certainly $\phi$ is dominant. See (3) (4) in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CC1

Comment: @EvansGambit Thank you fo you answer. The point is that I don't manage to show this injectivity.

Comment: By your assumption $\mathcal{O}_Y$ is the subsheaf of invariants $I_{\phi}$, which by definition is a subsheaf of $\phi_*\mathcal{O}_X$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @EvansGambit I agree, but why does that mean that $\phi^*(U):\mathcal I_\phi(U)\rightarrow\phi_*\mathcal O_X(U)$ is injective?

I mean, if a ring $A$ is a subring of $B$, there possibly exists a morphism $A\rightarrow B$ which is not injective, right? Of course in our case I would like to affirm that $\phi_*(U):\mathcal I_\phi(U)\rightarrow\phi_*\mathcal O_X(U)$ is just the inclusion, but I do not see why this is so obvious.